# .scrollLeft doesn't work in Fancybox popup

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a Shopify site where I created a .scrollLeft function that works fine if used on any of divs on normal page. But where I need it is the popup image of the product. It opens in fancybox popup and the scrollbar will not move.

**Demo link** - It is created to work only on mobile so you should resize your browser to see the action by clicking on any of the products and then click on the product image to open it in popup: https://qn7bzvvrmyldufbu-5801077.shopifypreview.com

This is my code, any ideas how to make it work in popup?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.fancybox-placeholder").scrollLeft(100); ///this is for popup
  $("div.product-default-image").scrollLeft(100); ///this is for normal element
 });
 </script>
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: It is not possible to help you without seeing a live page/demo. I do not know what Fancybox version are you using, but here you can find similar demos for v4 - https://fancyapps.com/showcase

Comment: I added a demo link

Comment: Your code snippet `$("div.fancybox-placeholder").scrollLeft(100);` works. You have many JS errors on the page, try to get rid of them.